# App crashes when fetching record from address book

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I need to fetch record from address book. I'm using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to do so. While fetching record I'm putting a check condition to check record exist or not.
For example to check there is first name I'm using the following code

```
NSString *fname;
CFTypeRef fnameProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)) {
    fname = (__bridge NSString*)fnameProperty;
}
else{
    fname = @"";
}
```

The code works perfectly for kABPersonFirstNameProperty.

But when I'm using following piece of code to check email property

```
ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSLog(@"%@",emailProperty);
NSString *email;
if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)) {
    email = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailProperty, 0);
}
else {
   email = @"";
}
```

My app crashes if kABPersonEmailProperty is nil(there is no email property stored for the person)

Can somebody explain me why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: please post the error that is shown

Comment: @Dpk error is

EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's is my working version, see if this works.

```
//Email
NSString* email = nil;
ABMultiValueRef emailNum = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                 kABPersonEmailProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emailNum) > 0) {
    email = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailNum, 0);
} else {
    email = @"";
}
```

Comment: Your if statement isn't checking if there is or isn't an email.

Comment: The contact you're trying it on probably has a name and no email?